# Laravel Dingo get data from multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel, dingo-api

I'm trying to retrieve data from two tables with relationship one-to-many. I need it to return in one response since it will be displayed simultaneously. However, I don't understand how to return extended object. For now I have something like this in controller

```
public function show(Site $id)
    {
        foreach ($id->features() as $feature) {
            $id->features[] = $feature;
        }

        return $id;
    }
```

And this is my model

```
class Site extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['path', 'site_link'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function features() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SiteFeature');
    }
}
```

For now it returns an empty array of features property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using implicit model binding then Lazy eager Load `features` relationship in controller action because model is already loaded

```
public function show(Site $site)
{
    $site->load('features');

    return $site;
}
```

If no implicit model binding then Eager load `features` using `with` at time of model loading

```
public function show($id)
{
    $site = Site::with('features')->find($id);

    return $site;
}
```

Check details for loading relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: Why doesn't it work if I try to use `with` instead of `load`

Comment: @Sergey when model is already loaded then to load their relationship we have to use `load` which is called `Lazy eager loading` but if model is not loaded yet then you can specify your relationship name using `with` keyword at time of model load that is called `Eager Loading`. For details you can check the link in answer. Hope it may clear you